# Android Studio 2.0 - code editing deadly slow

Tags: performance, android-studio

While i agree on the emulators being really faster, the editing process is slower than previous version: whenever i hit a key, AS stops for a lot of seconds. It became so slow to the point that i have to code in Power Save Mode. What can i do to speed up it without turning on PSM?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Ever since 2.0 the gradle build and start up has been extremely slow and unresponsive.

Comment: I have posted an answer to my own comment, since i have found that code inspections was the cause (at least for me).

Comment: The vertical scroll is choppy in editor on AS 2.1.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the code inspections is taking too much CPU time. I do not know exactly what are the differences between AS 2.0 and the previous version, but i found a way to code again by disabling a lot of inspections (performance, security, usability and so on) and disabling some of the inspection warnings (especially in the Android->Lint->Correctness group).

Comment: This is still not resolving the vertical scroll choppiness in Editor. Scrolling even a plain txt file is not that smooth as it was on AS <2.0.